# healpy.sphtfunc.smoothing takes 2800x longer on remote Linux machine than local Mac

Tags: python, performance, numpy, healpy

I have a collection of `healpy` maps I want to blur with `healpy.sphtfunc.smoothing`. Things run smoothly on my Macbook Pro but on the remote Linux machine we use for testing, I have found the tests stall due to the `healpy.sphtfunc.smoothing` taking in some cases 2700x longer to execute! Here's a MWE:

```py
def test_hp_smooth_mwe():
    import numpy as np
    import os, platform, sys, time
    import healpy as hp
    print(os.name, platform.system(), platform.release())
    print(hp.__version__)
    print(sys.version)
    resp_matrix = 10 * np.random.random(size=(5, 64, 768))
    times = np.zeros((5, 64))
    for i in range(resp_matrix.shape[0]):
        for j in range(resp_matrix.shape[1]):
            t0 = time.time()
            resp_matrix[i, j, :] = hp.sphtfunc.smoothing(
                resp_matrix[i, j, :], fwhm=np.deg2rad(10)
            )
            times[i, j] = time.time() - t0
    assert False, f"mean smoothing time: {times.mean():.3e} s"
```

My Macbook Pro result:

```
posix Darwin 18.7.0
1.15.0
3.8.10 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, May 10 2021, 22:58:09) 
[Clang 11.1.0 ]
AssertionError: mean smoothing time: 4.865e-04 s
```

Remote Linux machine result, running in the test environment:

```
posix Linux 5.8.0-43-generic
1.15.0
3.6.14 (default, Aug 17 2021, 16:32:35) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110]
AssertionError: mean smoothing time: 1.360e+00 s
```

Remote Linux machine result, running in the Python interpreter:

```
posix Linux 5.8.0-43-generic
1.15.0
3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40) 
[GCC 9.3.0]
AssertionError: mean smoothing time: 3.423e-04 s
```

(Don't mind the strange import patterns and the `assert False`, that's just to get it to work easily on the remote testing machine.)

As we can see, smoothing in the remote Linux test environment takes 2800x longer than on my local machine. As far as I can tell, no other operation experiences such a drastic slowdown, just the smoothing. Note also I see this slowdown on python 3.6, 3.7, and 3.8.

The test environment uses docker---could that slow things down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hp.sphtfunc.smoothing` turns out to be very compute-intensive, briefly flaring up all 16 threads on the runner to ~60% utilization. In the test environment, this was running on python 3.6, 3.7, and 3.8 *at the same time*, causing a bottleneck. If I test just 3.6 on its own, for example, I get the expected mean time of ~5e-04 s.

Answer (score 0):

It is really strange, I tested on my Linux laptop and I get:

```
posix Linux 5.4.119-14945-gafc97d54f809
1.15.0
3.8.0 (default, Nov  6 2019, 21:49:08) 
[GCC 7.3.0]
mean smoothing time: 5.515e-04 s
```

Difference seems to big to be explained with a threading issue, but you maybe   can check if there is something strange with linking:

```
ldd _healpy_sph_transform_lib.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe29b71000)
        libcurl-8a7386dc.so.4.7.0 => /home/zonca/miniconda3/envs/simple/lib/python3.8/site-packages/healpy/./../healpy.libs/libcurl-8a7386dc.so.4.7.0 (0x00007e31b0462000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007e31b02cf000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007e31b014c000)
        libgomp-3300acd3.so.1.0.0 => /home/zonca/miniconda3/envs/simple/lib/python3.8/site-packages/healpy/./../healpy.libs/libgomp-3300acd3.so.1.0.0 (0x00007e31aff3c000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007e31aff22000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007e31afeff000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007e31afd3e000)
        libz-a147dcb0.so.1.2.3 => /home/zonca/miniconda3/envs/simple/lib/python3.8/site-packages/healpy/./../healpy.libs/libz-a147dcb0.so.1.2.3 (0x00007e31afb29000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007e31afb24000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007e31b0f93000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007e31afb1a000)
```

I would try installing `healpy` from another source. So if you installed with Conda, try pip or the other way around.
Last test would be to build from source.

Comment: I ssh'd into the Linux machine, installed healpy with pip, and got a mean time of 3.423e-04 s in the interpreter. I realized the test environment uses Docker, maybe that's part of the issue? I also tried the linker as above and got essentially the same as you.

Comment: yeah it's probably docker, it might have CPU or memory limits